# Как сделать эффект прозрачности всей формы с ее контролами?

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть форма, хочу чтобы при наведении курсора видимость была 70%, а при покидании курсором формы - 50%. Как мне это сделать?

Comment: [Form.Opacity](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.opacity?view=netframework-4.7.2) ?

Comment: И вновь, спасибо.